# How do I block Semalt on IIS

Tags: iis, web-config, spam, spam-prevention

Checking my Google Analytics I'm getting a lot of traffic from semalt.com.
I know this is a traffic spam tactic, so I want to completely block their requests and stop it from turning up in my traffic stats.

I read here http://logorrhoea.net/2014/01/how-to-block-semalt-com-referrer-traffic-using-htaccess/ that on Apache it can be done like:

```
# block visitors referred from semalt.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

but I need it for IIS, probably via the web.config, but how to do it?

Comment: Recently, I also see "semalt.semalt.com" as referers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found something here: http://tusksoft.com/blog/posts/6/clean-up-your-google-analytics-and-help-stop-referer-spam-with-this-simple-rewrite-rule:

This seems to work:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="abort referer spam requests" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="(semalt\.com)|(buttons\-for\-website\.com)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>
    <!--The rest of your rules, if you have any-->
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks @Flo The most anoying on all my sites are social-buttons.com so added them in the system.webServer 
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="abort referer spam requests" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="(semalt\.com)|(buttons\-for\-website\.com)|(social\-button\.com)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>
    <!--The rest of your rules, if you have any-->
  </rules>
</rewrite>

Comment: To add to my answer: not all referral spam sets a referrer hostname, so these will still popup in you Google Analytics log.
Found this great post here: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics

summary: what it does is check if a visitor sets a valid hostname (as in: your sites hostname or a known hostname). If not, you can filter that out of your reports. So  instead of excluding all spam sites (and having to maintain that list) it includes only valid visits. Check Audience > Technology > Network > hostname to see the hostnames of your sites' requests.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it should work:

```
       <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="*.semalt.com*" 

ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="AbortRequest" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

I have tested and verified this but for a referrer URL other than *.semalt.com. The key in this code, different from your code, is a wildcard at the end of the referrer pattern because the referer URL ends with a "/". You can also replace the wildcard at the end with a "/" though I think a wildcard should be better.

Answer (score 2):

What follows is a sample web.config with a equivalent URL Rewrite configuration to the one you have provided.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="block semalt referer" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="*.semalt.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I answered my own post earlier with that exact same rule, but I still go semalt in my Google Analytics traffic stats....so for some reason this rule does not work.

Comment: I had other rules with `stopProcessing="true"`, so make sure this is the first entry in your `<rules>`.